# Choi type matrix condition for completely positivity on a certain operator system spanned by some unitaries

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, matrix-theory, complete-positivity

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be $C^*$-algebras. Let $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ be some unitaries in $B_1.$ We consider the operator system $S$ spanned by $U_iU_j^*.$

Let $\phi: S \rightarrow B_2.$

Given that the block matrix $[\phi(U_iU_j^*)]_{1 \leq i,j\leq n}$ is positive semidefinite, can we conclude that $\phi$ is completely positive?

Comment: Do you mean that $S$ is the $C^*$-algebra generated by the $U_i U_j^*$ ?

Comment: No, I mean the operator system.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_system

Comment: Then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_positive_map needs a modification .

Comment: @jjcale - Does it? Choi's theorem applies to $C^*$-algebras, which is what the Wikipedia article says. The current question is asking whether or not this version involving operator systems also holds. Neither Choi's theorem nor the proposed theorem here are (as far as I can tell) generalizations of each other.

Comment: In the Wikipedia article the domain of the completly positive map is a $C^*$-algebra, that is what I mean. In this article Choi isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no :
Let $U_1 = I$, where $I$ is the identity and $U_2$ linear independent to $I$ such that $U_2^* + U_2 \ge 0$ .
Then choose $\phi(U_1) = I$ and $\phi(U_2) = -I$ .

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to prove something and the claim came up (in some special case.) So I guess I must need more assumptions.